# why is my content showing outside the div?

Tags: css, html

I have a "bubble" with content, which is working fine. Now, I want to display a count (2 lines) which should always be in the bottom right corner of that div, INSIDE it. I tried many things but for some reason it always overlaps the div and shows outside. What am I doing wrong?

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-color:#f3f3f3;
}
.commentbox{
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 200px;
border-color: #D1D1D1;
border-radius: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px; 
padding-bottom: 9px;
padding-left: 9px;
padding-right: 9px;
padding-top: 9px;
position:relative;
}
.count{
float:right;
text-align:right;
}
</style>

<div class="commentbox">
<div class="title">Some several lines long long long long content text goes here 
</div>
<div class="count">123<br>456</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are floating `.count` so it doesn't influence it's parent container's height.

Set `overflow: hidden` on the parent (`.commentbox`) or use [one of the other float containing techniques](https://web.archive.org/web/20130707085000/http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59) so that it does.

Comment: @SangramNandkhile — Link fixed, but the method in the question is still almost always the best one.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need `float: right;` for `.count`? I think `text-align` should be enough for the desired layout.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using `position:relative` on the parent div. Try this instead:

```
.count {
   position:absolute;
   right:0;
   bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: That risks making the count text overlap with the title text.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have to add a clear after the "count" div.

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-color:#f3f3f3;
}
.commentbox{
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 200px;
border-color: #D1D1D1;
border-radius: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px; 
padding-bottom: 9px;
padding-left: 9px;
padding-right: 9px;
padding-top: 9px;
position:relative;
}
.count{
float:right;
text-align:right;
}
</style>

<div class="commentbox">
<div class="title">Some several lines long long long long content text goes here 
</div>
<div class="count">123<br>456</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding extra markup to contain floats is a really ugly approach to the problem.