# How to make background apply to entire div

Tags: css, html, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why is my content showing outside the div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062255/why-is-my-content-showing-outside-the-div)

I have a problem where the background style for a div doesn't cover everything nested inside the div.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eq3Wx/) to show you exactly what I'm talking about

How can I make the grey background style from the div `ddg-corner-statements` apply to everything inside the div without setting an absolute height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue when working with floats. There are a couple of common solutions:

1. Add a div after the floats with `clear: both`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/).

   ```
   <div style="float: left"></div>
   <div style="float: left"></div>
   <div style="clear: both"></div>
   ```
2. Add the two floats into a container with the CSS attribute `overflow: auto`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/1/).

   ```
   <div style="overflow: auto">
       <div style="float: left"></div>
       <div style="float: left"></div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Make the parent element a float. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/2/).

   ```
   <div style="float: left">
       <div style="float: left"></div>
       <div style="float: left"></div>
   </div>
   ```
4. Use the :after CSS pseudo element. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/3/).

   ```
   .parentelement:after {
       content: ".";
       display: block;
       height: 0; 
       clear: both; 
       visibility: hidden;
   }
   ```
5. Adding a set height to the parent element. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/4/).

   ```
   <div style="height: 200px">
       <div style="float: left"></div>
       <div style="float: left"></div>
   </div>
   ```

Personally, I use option 2 for simplicity and semantics' sake

See an updated version of your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Eq3Wx/4/).

Comment: yes .. your option 2 is help me !! Thanx ..

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to apply grey background color to everything : [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Eq3Wx/5/)

Clear your floats like this :

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="view-all-statements"><a href="ddg-statements.html">View All Statements →</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The grey background seem to be an image. Try repeating it vertically and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve yout problem:

```
> .ddg-corner-statements {
>     padding: 10px 15px 1px;
>     background: url("../images/bg_story_resources_bot.gif") repeat-x scroll left bottom transparent;
>     display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The background isn't being applied because your child elements are floated and taken out of the flow.

```
.ddg-corner-sidebar ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-top: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 0 9px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you remove `float:left;` the background will perform as expected.

If the `float:left` is required you will need to clear your floats.