# HTML Divisions Location

Tags: css, html

I was making a new design for my website. I thought that I should make different boxes. All of their `borders` and `backgrounds` had to be same, but their `heights` and `widths` had to be different. So, I created a css class.

```
.box
{
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,90,255,0.5) 0%, rgba(0,90,255,0.5) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,90,255,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,90,255,0.5)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,90,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,90,255,0.5) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,90,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,90,255,0.5) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,90,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,90,255,0.5) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,90,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,90,255,0.5) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#80005aff', endColorstr='#80005aff',GradientType=1 );

    border:thick white groove;
    border-bottom-color:gray;
    border-right-color:gray;
    border-top-left-radius:1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:1em;

}
```

---

I put the HTML code in the body as -

```
    <body onload="load()">

    <center>

        <div style="width:1120px">
            <img src="images/blu-logo.png" style="float:left;">     
            <div class="box" style="width:900px;height:50px;float:right;margin-top:100px;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box" style="width:900px;height:500px;">
            <p>Sample text</p>
        </div>          
    </center>

</body>
```

---

I don't know how but something crazy happened when I viewed the file in the browser as the division(`<div>`) that was supposed to be **below** the other actually went on the same position as the first one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is my content showing outside the div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062255/why-is-my-content-showing-outside-the-div)

Comment: Just a note to say that the <center> tag is now deprecated and as such shouldn't really be used anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is to do with your floating elements.

Try and the css property "overflow:auto" onto the DIV which contains the two floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the floated div/img - you can add an empty div with a style attribute or give it a clear class to use for other elements (br is an option as well)