# Expand Content Area

Tags: css, html

I have a webpage which uses this [tabs script](http://fotis.co/projects/simpletabs/) on it.  I want to add a two column layout to one of the tabs, and I am using the following code:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="con con-left">
        Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="con con-right">
        Column 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Which works with this CSS:

```
.content-wrapper
{   width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; }
.con
{   margin: 0 10px;
    float: left; 
    display: inline; }
.con-left
{   width: 500px; }
.con-right
{   width: 500px; }
```

The problem is the size of the tab does not expand for the amount of text that is insidethe div - as shown in the image below.  How can I set the CSS so that the tabs will recognise the content within the `<div>` tags?

[image]

Comment: display block and clear:both on .con will prob work...

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is my content showing outside the div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062255/why-is-my-content-showing-outside-the-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't set a width on inline elements - make them `inline-block` and remove the float so the wrapper will wrap properly.

If you want to keep the float then, either use a `clear` after your floated elements or add `overflow:auto` to the wrapper

Comment: Magic!  Worked a treat thanks!  Will accept as the answer when I am allowed to!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use floats, you need to clear them.

You could try:

```
.content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Setting `overflow: auto` on the containing block will enclose all your floats as you expect.